# How to insert MySQL BIT(1) field value using Drupal 7 API?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, bit

I have database table with following fields.

Table = TestForm
Fields:

```
id  INT AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
name VARCHAR(255)
status BIT(1)
```

I have use following to insert data in Drupal 7:

```
db_insert('TestForm')
->fields(array(
    'name' => "My Form",
    'status' => "b'1'"
))->execute();
```

Can anyone let me know how to insert data using Drupal 7 db_insert API for BIT(1) field.

Comment: If you don't get an answer for BIT(1), switch to TINYINT.

Answer (score 1):

Bit(1) type somehow equals to BOOL. So the answer would be:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO {TestForm} (name, status) VALUES ('My Form', TRUE)";
db_query($q);
```

We use plain **db_query** (**NOT** db_insert) and **TRUE/FALSE** because otherwise drupal will preprocess it to int and it will throw "too long" error.

Note that **you can't** even add this TRUE/FALSE to params for db_query and pass like :**status**, because it still will be converted.

Hope it will save "a bit" time for someone...  :)